# Upload image using html

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a simple chat application using google App engine. I am using the code available from this link.

http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/simple-ajax-chat/

I am new to the concepts of HTML, CSS and Javascript. I wish to add another feature to the chat application where the user can upload an image in the chat window itself. (Similar to the feature that we have in facebook).

I explored the code and found out that the following HTML code takes care of the chat window.

```
<div id="chats"></div>
<form id="send-chat-form" action="javascript:sendChat();">
<div class="form-item">
<input type="text" name="content" class="form-textfield" id="chattext" size="100" />
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Send" />
<input type="button" class="form-refresh" value="Refresh" onclick="updateChat()" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

The sendChat() function looks like below.

```
function sendChat(form) {
if (isNotEmpty(document.getElementById("chattext").value)) {
downloadUrl(getRandomUrl("/getchats"), "POST", "content=" +   
encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("chattext").value), onChatsReturned);
document.getElementById("chattext").value = "";
}
}
```

Since, I wish to incorporate the image features, I modified my code as per the below link.

http://saravani.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/preview-of-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded/

After modification, my HTML code is like below.

```
<div class="form-item">
<input type="text" name="content" class="form-textfield" id="chattext" size="100" />
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="img_prev" src="#" alt="your image"/>
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Send" />
<input type="button" class="form-refresh" value="Refresh" onclick="updateChat()" />
</div>
```

I modified the sendchat() function as below.

```
function sendChat(form) {`
if (isNotEmpty(document.getElementById("chattext").value)) {
downloadUrl(getRandomUrl("/getchats"), "POST", "content=" + 
encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("chattext").value), onChatsReturned);
downloadUrl(getRandomUrl("/getchats"), "POST", "content=" + 
encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("img_prev").src), onChatsReturned);
document.getElementById("chattext").value = "";
}
}
}
```

Basically, I am trying to display the image in the chat window itself. I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: I belive the probelm here: `if (isNotEmpty(document.getElementById("chattext").value))` try use this instead `if (document.getElementById("chattext").value == "")`

Comment: If I use, if (document.getElementById("chattext").value == ""), when I try to send some text, won't it be a problem?